# Android TextToSpeech (TTS) format number

Tags: android, text-to-speech

I have in my application a string composed by several words, including numbers, which are separeted by comma.
Sometimes the TTS engine reproduces the number digit by digit and other times as a whole number (i.e three houndred and thirty two).
What I need is that all time it reads the number as a whole number and not digit by digit.
Moreover I need that it reprocudes decimals (24.35 = twenty for comma thirty five) That is the way I am looking for.

Can anyone help me to do this? What is the difference for the engine to say digits or de whole number?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you please post your code so people can see how it functions and advise you based on how it's working?

Comment: Try replacing "." with " comma ". i.e.: `"24.35"` => `"24 comma 35"` (but I'd better use "point" rather than "comma"). It will speak it out correctly, then.

Comment: I also tried it with the number 20.025 => 20 coma 025. However it says two cero comma twenty five. It interprets the second part as a whole number ( so it removes de first cero) but the first one digit by digit.

Comment: Weird. Did you update the TTS Engine? Because my device(s) can speak 20 correctly. And so do my emulators.

Comment: How can I update it?

Comment: Google Play will notify when it's time to update. Or go to the Play app and manually search for updates.

Comment: For "20 comma 025" skipping the leading 0... this can be avoided replacing the leading "0" with "0 ". So, it should speak "0-twentyfive".

Comment: what tts do you use? Samsung motor or Google syntesis?

Comment: Google **standard**. Also, because I'm not so rich to can afford a Samsung.

Comment: No I meant that in settings, language, text to voice options there are 2 available free options, Samsung motor or google syntesis. Both are free because I have never paid anything

Comment: With samsungo motor it reads two cero comma twenty five. However with google syntesis it reads twenty coma cero two five.